# solr fq syntax for an OR query

Tags: solr

Just wondering what the correct syntax for an fq query would be...

Is it, example #1:

```
fq=(attr__sku__suitability__s:1-3yrs) OR 
(attr__sku__suitability__s:3-6yrs) OR 
(attr__sku__suitability__s:6-12yrs) OR 
(attr__sku__suitability__s:0-3mths) OR 
(attr__sku__suitability__s:3-12mths)
```

Or, example #2 :

```
fq=attr__sku__suitability__s:(1-3yrs OR 3-6yrs OR 6-12yrs OR 0-3mths OR 3-12mths)
```

Or something else I've completely overlooked

(url encoding has been left out to make it easier to read)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com. Please try to format your question so it is easier to read.

Comment: please include the actual values (few examples), default query type, and data type that stored into `attr__sku__suitability__s`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both examples are OK and have the same behaviour, you could even remove parentheses from the first example.