# Solr fq: Syntax for an OR query with field QParser

Tags: solr

So an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260742/solr-fq-syntax-for-an-or-query) is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. However, the twist with my issue is that I'm using the "field" value for QParser to not require escaping values so the syntax is quite different.

Example of my fq:  `fq={!field f=category}some value`

I've tried various combinations to include my OR values within the query but the search returns 0 results or can't parse it correctly.

A couple approaches I've tried are:

`fq={!field f=category}(some value OR some other value)`

`fq={!field f=category}some value OR {!field f=category}some other value`

`fq=({!field f=category}(some value OR some other value))`

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. try this

```
fq=({!field f=category})somevalue OR othervalue
```

Comment: It's able to parse it however it's not matching correctly compared to if I try it without the {!field f=category} at all, which does work. Maybe this is just a matter of making sure I escape all of the correct characters and ditch trying to use the field parser.